# How to redirect a second domain to first domain with specific path and variable

Tags: .htaccess, variables, redirect, path, dns

Please help, I need my second domain simplify URL on first domain like this :

```
http://second.domain/"username_variable"
```

showing

```
http://first.domain/jobseeker/site/cv/username/"username_variable"
```

The second domain is an add-on domain to the first domain.

Can I do that with htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

In the htaccess file in your second domain's document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} second.domain [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://first.domain/jobseeker/site/cv/username/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've tried it and the redirection works fine. But sorry i forgot to mention that i need the URL does not change to http://first.domain/jobseeker/site/cv/username/"someuser" but showing http://second.domain/"someuser". How to do that?

Comment: @MasriSabarani Only way for that to work is to reverse proxy, and it requires that mod_proxy is loaded in apache. You'll need to make  sure it's loaded and change the `R=301` to `P`.